# WeConnect Library - Extract Data from a Type Class

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm using the WeConnect Library to get information about my car from VW.

I can print out the status of car doors and etc.

```
>>> print(vehicle.domains["access"]["accessStatus"])

[accessStatus] (last captured 2022-12-16T15:25:12+00:00)
    Overall Status: safe
    Door Lock Status: locked
    Doors: 6 items
        bonnet: closed, unknown lock state
        frontLeft: closed, locked
        frontRight: closed, locked
        rearLeft: closed, locked
        rearRight: closed, locked
        trunk: closed, locked
    Windows: 6 items
        frontLeft: closed
        frontRight: closed
        rearLeft: closed
        rearRight: closed
        roofCover: unsupported
        sunRoof: closed

>>> print(type(vehicle.domains["access"]["accessStatus"]))
<class 'weconnect.elements.access_status.AccessStatus'>
```

How do I go about getting a specific value out of this type class i.e "Door Lock Status" as this appears to be a dictionary. But I get a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francis\Documents\MyProjects\Python\WeConnect\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(vehicle.domains["access"]["accessStatus"]["Door Lock Status"])
TypeError: 'AccessStatus' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a method to export `asDict()`:

```
a = vehicle.domains["access"]["accessStatus"].asDict()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'overallStatus': <OverallState.SAFE: 'safe'>, 'doorLockStatus': <LockState.LOCKED: 'locked'>, 'doors': {'bonnet': {'lockState': <LockState.UNKNOWN: 'unknown lock state'>, 'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'frontLeft': {'lockState': <LockState.LOCKED: 'locked'>, 'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'frontRight': {'lockState': <LockState.LOCKED: 'locked'>, 'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'rearLeft': {'lockState': <LockState.LOCKED: 'locked'>, 'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'rearRight': {'lockState': <LockState.LOCKED: 'locked'>, 'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'trunk': {'lockState': <LockState.LOCKED: 'locked'>, 'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}}, 'windows': {'frontLeft': {'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'frontRight': {'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'rearLeft': {'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'rearRight': {'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}, 'roofCover': {'openState': <OpenState.UNSUPPORTED: 'unsupported'>}, 'sunRoof': {'openState': <OpenState.CLOSED: 'closed'>}}, 'carCapturedTimestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 17, 19, 30, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
```